# Dataframe row shuffling

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to shuffle rows in a dataframe in-place and reset the index using

`df = df.sample(frac=-1).reset_index(drop=True)`

But when I do that it tells me to provide a positive frac value.
`ValueError: A negative number of rows requested. Please provide positive value.`
Help.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your df?

Comment: Why frac = -1, negative? Just use 1 for sampling 100%. *fracfloat, optional
Fraction of axis items to return. Cannot be used with n.*

Comment: @mullinscr Yeah its a 5 rows x 208 columns dataframe
                 id      col1    col2    col3    ...     col206  col207   col208
0 id_000bb2 0     0      0         ...     0     0          -1   
1 id_0009bfc 0     0      0         ...     0     0          -1   
2 id_00066a 0     0      0         ...     0     0          -1   
3 id_001391 0     0      0         ...     0     0          -1   
4 id_001bd3

Comment: so basically like @ScottBoston said frac should be a positive number, it represents the percentage of your dataframe you want to sample
like 0.5 you want a random sample of with length half of your original dataframe
frac=1 basically shuffles the dataframe
but -1 means nothing apparently.

Comment: @sripaadsrinivasan Yes.  Frac is a percent of the dataframe.  Sample half the dataframe.